# What does this piece of code mean in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble understanding this code:

```
SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
SaveFileDialog.FileName = "dummy.txt"
SaveFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"

If (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = 2) Then
    MsgBox("No dummy has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
Else
    Dim StreamWriter As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(SaveFileDialog.FileName)
```

I want to know what the **"2"** means at the beginning of the If statement in this code.

**Note: I didn't write this code. This is an example my teacher gave to us.**

Answer (score 3):

When you call the `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog` Method a `DialogResult` is returned. The `DialogResult` is an enumeration and look like this

```
public enum DialogResult
{
    None,    // 0
    OK,      // 1
    Cancel,  // 2 !!
    Abort,   // 3
    Retry,   
    Ignore,
    Yes,
    No,      // 7
}
```

In this case, each enumeration value has an implicit numerical index beginning from zero. In your code sample the code evaluates the `DialogResult` *based on the index* instead of the actual  enumeration value.

This means that evaluating whether the `DialogResult` is equal to 2 is equivalent to evaluating whether the `DialogResult` is equal to `DialogResult.Cancel`.

This means that when the user presses the *cancel* button on the dialog window, the `MessageBox` should be displayed informing the user that they did not select a file.

Answer (score 1):

2 is the dialog result (enumeration value) of the `ShowDialog` call.

The `DialogResult` maps to the following enumeration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx

So, by checking

```
If (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = 2) Then
    MsgBox("No dummy has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
```

the code is validating whether or not the user selected CANCEL on the dialog.

The code should also be written using the enumeration value for the check, which makes it more clear:

```
If (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
    MsgBox("No dummy has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
```